# Certificate Outlook expired

Tags: outlook, certificate

I have all my mails account in Office 365.

I have updated the certificate of my website. Since this moment, I receive an alert message every time I start Outlook [Certificate is expired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QU74Z.jpg)

If I click on see certificate, it shows me the previous certificate, not the renewed.

Outlook run normally. How i can delete the alert?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Have you install or check a new SSL certificate for your client? Please see this links:

[Outlook Client and Security Alerts for expired security certificate](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/office-365-outlook-client-and-security-alerts-for/cc56faf9-c66c-43f3-8228-b8b1f8ef37e2)

[The security certificate has expired or is not yet valid](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365/The-security-certificate-has-expired-or-is-not-yet-valid/td-p/177489)

Updated:

You might need to contact the server admin to renew the certificate, please refer to the link:

[Renew an Exchange Server certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/architecture/client-access/renew-certificates?view=exchserver-2019)

[image]

[image]

Comment: No, i dont install a new certificate for my Outlook. How i can do it?

Comment: @davostoff I've updated my answer, please check your certificate e.g. domain issue ?

Comment: But we have our mail acounts on Office365, and the link you send me its for Exchange

Comment: @davostoff You might need to know relationship between the Client side and Server side.1.Confirm whether the certificate installed on the Exchange is renewed.
2. Remove the old Exchange certificate on your local computer:

Comment: Please see my new updated, remove old exchange certificate steps screenshot as above.

Comment: Thanks for you support my friend. I solved it. It was an error in the configuration of the web server.
The certificate for the web was not configured without www. Thanks!